# wp_get_nav_menu_items multi level submenu

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to create my own menu in WordPress with a submenu that holds items ass well. The way below I can have nested links until --C but not ---D

```
-A
-B
--C
---D
-E
-F
```

I have this function:

```
function wp_get_menu_array($current_menu) {
  $array_menu = wp_get_nav_menu_items($current_menu);
  $menu = array();
  foreach ($array_menu as $m) {
      if (empty($m->menu_item_parent)) {
          $menu[$m->ID] = array();
          $menu[$m->ID]['ID']          =   $m->ID;
          $menu[$m->ID]['title']       =   $m->title;
          $menu[$m->ID]['url']         =   $m->url;
          $menu[$m->ID]['children']    =   array();
      }
  }
  $submenu = array();
  foreach ($array_menu as $m) {
      if ($m->menu_item_parent) {
          $submenu[$m->ID] = array();
          $submenu[$m->ID]['ID']       =   $m->ID;
          $submenu[$m->ID]['title']    =   $m->title;
          $submenu[$m->ID]['url']      =   $m->url;
          $menu[$m->menu_item_parent]['children'][$m->ID] = $submenu[$m->ID];
      }
  }
  return $menu;
}
```

And to render the nav:

```
<?php foreach ($menu_items as $item) : ?>
<?php $current = ( $item->object_id == get_queried_object_id() ) ? 'current' : '' ?>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link <?= $current ?>" href="<?= $item['url'] ?>" title="<?= $item['title'] ?>"><?= $item['title'] ?></a>
    <?php if( !empty($item['children']) ):?>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
    <?php foreach($item['children'] as $child): ?>
        <li class="b-main-header__sub-menu__nav-item">
        <a href="<?= $child['url'] ?>" title="<?= $child['title'] ?>"><?= $child['title'] ?></a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I just cannot figure out how I would implement a multi level submenu. At the moment when I create a submenu which holds items as well it will create those items as individual menu items.

Hope my clarification is well enough and somebody can help me out here.

Comment: Nested ```nav links``` can get very confusing if you do it this way! I would first register my ```nav menu``` in the ```functions.php``` and then in the ```admin area > appearance > menus ``` I would use drag and drop functionality to sort the nested links. It would make my life much easier this way!

Comment: I am doing this exactly. The function I showed is in `functions.php` and am creating the primary menu in `admin area > appearance > menus`. Then in `header.php` I am setting up the navigation as per the last piece of code.